# How to check if any of files is missing

Tags: java, android, toast

I use the following code to check if a file exists in a folder in sdcard:

```
//Check if database exists
    File fia = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/my_folder/db/my_file_1");
    if(fia.exists())
       {                        
         //do something 
       }                        
   else
    {                       
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Database is not available. Please install it.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                      
    }
```

This code works well.

Now I have 5 known files stored in different subfolders of `sdcard/my_folder/` as:

```
1. sdcard/my_folder/db/my_file_1 
2. sdcard/my_folder/db/my_file_2
3. sdcard/my_folder/abc/my_file_3
4. sdcard/my_folder/abc/my_file_3
5. sdcard/my_folder/xyz/my_file_5
```

The problem is that I want to check if all the files exist, then do something. And if any of the above files is not available or missing, then display a Toast message.

I have no idea how to display the Toast message just one time if any of the files does not exist (manually doing this displays the Toast message whenever a file is not available, which is not my wish).

Can you please give a little help? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
File fia = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/my_folder/db/my_file_1");
File fia2 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/my_folder/db/my_file_2");
File fia3 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/my_folder/abc/my_file_3");
File fia4 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/my_folder/abc/my_file_3");
File fia5 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/my_folder/xyz/my_file_5");
if(fia.exists() && fia2.exists() && fia3.exists() && fia4.exists() && fia5.exists())
   {                        
     //do something 
   } else {                       
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Database is not available. Please install it.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                      
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add method to check several paths

```
private boolean checkFileExists(String path) {
    File file = new File(path);
    return file.exists();
}

private boolean checkAllFilesExist(String[] ... paths) {
    if (paths != null && paths.length > 0) {
        for (String path : paths) {
            if (!checkFileExists(path)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;    
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

if (!checkAllFilesExist("/path1", "/path2")) {
    // some of them missed
}
```

Answer (score 1):

put your file names to an string array then check it in a loop, like below

```
ArrayList<String> arrFiles= new ArrayList<String>();
arrFiles.add(sdcard/my_folder/db/my_file_1 );
arrFiles.add(sdcard/my_folder/db/my_file_2 );
arrFiles.add(sdcard/my_folder/db/my_file_3 );
arrFiles.add(sdcard/my_folder/db/my_file_4 );
Boolean isOk=true;

for(String s : arrFiles){

File fia = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+s);
    if(fia.exists())
       {                        
          // it is ok
       }                        
   else
    {                       
      isOk=false;
    } 

}
```

Then isok = true it is ok.